# Media Queries Work Correctly Locally But Not On Live Site

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm building a Wordpress site for a friend. Until I can complete his website, I created a temporary static page. I pushed the code and assets up to a Digital Ocean Droplet.

**My problem**: They media queries work correctly on my local development environment, but not on the live site.

When I view the local site on my iPhone 5s, it formats correctly. When I deploy the code to the production environment it seem the media queries are being ignored.

I'm able to reproduce this problem in my dev environment by removing the viewport meta tag. I don't understand what's going on.

**Website**: http://princetonrevival.com

Comment: Hi your site does not have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">, please add this to your head section and test again

Comment: First, I would avoid using framesets, as those are deprecated and tend to produce weird effects on modern browsers (if you're having issues, I wouldn't be surprised if that's the reason).
Second, it displays fine for me, except on screen widths greater than 1600px (at which point it becomes largely unstyled). This appears to be because you have no media queries addressing this width.

Comment: PRAH: he does have the viewport set, it's just set inside of the frameset, instead of in the main 'Head' tag, like you'd expect.

Comment: Strange ... I just noticed the framesets which I did not code. So I accessed the site with the IP address and and the site looks good - no framesets.  

It seems to be an issue with the domain name which my friend bought from Godaddy. I'll head over there and see if I can figure out what may be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

DNS forwarding with masking was the problem.

**The Fix**: I had to modify the GoDaddy domain settings. I added the three Digital Ocean name servers and enabled domain forward only.

After about an hour, everything worked and the mobile layout was correct.